# Start and Stop Dragging not working properly

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to create a Start Drag and Stop Drag simple app. but it seems to not working properly. it starts dragging but it does't drop off the object anywhere

```
addChild(shampooing);
addChild(check_box);
check_box.gotoAndStop(2);
check_box.x = 40;
check_box.y = 550;

check_box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragObject);
check_box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragObject);
function dragObject(mn:MouseEvent):void
{
    xPos = check_box.x;
    yPos = check_box.y;

    check_box.startDrag(true);
}
function stopDragObject(l:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (check_box.hitTestObject(getChildByName("shampooing")))
    {
        check_box.x = getChildByName("shampooing").x;
        check_box.y = getChildByName("shampooing").y;
    }
    else
    {
        check_box.x = xPos;
        check_box.y = yPos;
    }

    check_box.stopDrag();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're explicitly setting the `name` property on your `shampooing` object to "shampooing," then `getChildByName("shampooing")` will throw an error. Since you already have a reference to `shampooing`, you can change your code to:

```
if (check_box.hitTestObject(shampooing))
{
    check_box.x = shampooing.x;
    check_box.y = shampooing.y;
}
```